# Has_one and has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have two tables, `registrations` and `discounts` that hold information on a registration and a discount, respectively. Each registration can have one discount, and each discount can have many registrations.

I'm able to pull all of the registrations for a discount when I do something such as `Discount.find(1).registrations`, but when I attempt to call `Registration.find(1).discount` I get the error

```
Unknown column 'discounts.registration_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `discounts`.* FROM `discounts`  WHERE `discounts`.`registration_id` = 1  ORDER BY `discounts`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1`
```

My models are currently set up as follows:

```
class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_one :payment
        has_one :discount
end

class Discount < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :registrations
end
```

Additionally, my `registration` table has a foreign key `discount_id`.

I can make the association work if I set up a `belongs_to` relationship in the `registrations` model, but registrations don't belong to discounts - they may or may not have one.

How should I set up this relationship? Should I set up another table and use a `has_many, through` relationship?

Edit: I do not want to use a `belongs_to` relationship in my `registration` model, because a registration does not belong to a discount.

Answer (score 2):

If a discount can have many registration then you want to use belongs_to instead of has_one

```
class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :payment
    belongs_to :discount
end

class Discount < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :registrations
end
```

Check out this [explanation](http://duanesbrain.blogspot.ca/2006/05/ruby-on-rails-hasone-versus-belongsto.html) of the difference between belongs_to and has_one

Comment: I specifically do not want to use the `belongs_to` relationship, since the registration does not specifically belong to a discount. It can have one discount, but is not dependent on it in any way.

Comment: That's ok. ```belongs_to``` doesn't mean that you absolutely need the registration to have a discount. If you don't have one, ```your_registration.discount``` will simply return nil. You want to use has_one if you have a belongs_to on the other end. Like if let's say you have a description table and one discount ```has_one :description``` and a description ```belongs_to :discount``` If you really need them separated (but it might not be necessary in your case), then you want to use a join table like Rails Guy said. So bottom line is ```belongs_to``` or join table :)

Answer (score 0):

You should define your relationship like this:

```
class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :payment
  has_one :discountable
  has_one :discount, through: :discountable
end

class Discount < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :registration, through: :discountables
end

class Discountable < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :registration
  belongs_to :discount
end
```

Thanks

Comment: This seems wrong to me, since he indicated that a Discount can have many Registrations. With your solution we have a one-to-one relation, instead of one-to-many.

Comment: Yes @Flaxfield. The discount is already defined in the `discount` table. Each discount can have multiple registrations, and I can't add a `registration_id` column to the `discount` table since it wouldn't make sense in this relationship.

Comment: Ohh so sorry. I missed that line. Apologize for that. I will update my answer.